# How to execute a script via contab in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04

I have located a script in /bin/filename and i want to check it in contab if it's running every 2 min. How should my contab look like?

```
# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
0 2 * * * * root /bin/filename
#
```

Is it ok? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Misunderstood question. */2 for a job every 2 minutes. 
Then use below to see if its running

You can do something like this:
`cat /var/log/syslog | grep cron` 

to see just the cron entries in the system log.

Or open up /etc/rsyslog.conf and uncomment the line that looks like this
`cron.*    /var/log/cron.log`

That will create a file in /var/log which you can monitor with tail:

`tail -f /var/log/cron.log`

Answer (score 0):

```
*/2 *  * * *  root  /bin/filename
```

Comment: (Missing newline bef                       ore EOF, this crontab file will be ignored)
??

Comment: I think you should put a new line (press Enter) after the last line.